# Will I get Appstore notifications for auto renewable subscription during the Offer period?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am having an app which contains auto renewable subscription. The renewal of the subscription occurs every month. We have designed our app in a way that user get "1 credit" every month after the subscription renews. Now we have a new requirement in which we have to implement Offer Code or Promo Code which offers Subscription for free for a 1 year. Will we get monthly subscription renewal App Store notification during this offer period?. I just want to confirm this as there is no provision to test Offer codes in sandbox mode. This is critical to our design as if we don't get App Store notification user will not be credited his coin for 1 year.

Comment: Did you try to test it in your development/sandbox environment to find out?

Comment: When I went through the docs,  there is no option to test offer codes in sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I not sure you really need notifications.

You can read the app receipt on launch or foreground move ( you probably already do it ), enumerate all expired subscriptions and use expiration dates and other properties to get your credits.

By replaying the scenario, you can get the state at any past date up to now.